# Formulation of insert into keyword in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert some values to the table, there is an order such as 1,2,3....n

```
Insert Into table_name VALUES ( '1', 'A' )
Insert Into table_name VALUES ( '2', 'AA' )
Insert Into table_name VALUES ( '3', 'AAC' )
Insert Into table_name VALUES ( '.', '....' )
Insert Into table_name VALUES ( '.', '....' )
Insert Into table_name VALUES ( 'n', '....' )
```

How can I formulate this `INSERT` statement?

Comment: !?!?! What !?!?!? What's wrong with the INSERT statements your have (other than you should always also define what **columns** in the table you want to insert stuff into....). What do you mean by "there is an order......." - you already have `n` INSERT statements and they will be executed in the order they're written down.....

Comment: I want to learn are there any thing like this:
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Insert Into table_name VALUES(i, ....)
}

Comment: I want to make a loop in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to select the values to insert from somewhere else:

```
INSERT INTO company1.new_customers (id, name, address) 
SELECT 
  NULL   -- this will trigger the DB to auto-generate the new id's
  ,name
  ,address
FROM company2.old_customers
```

If you have to use a `loop` in SQL you're doing it wrong.
SQL works with sets.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert a series of rows - sure, you can use a loop - but how do you know what other values (other than the index) to get??

```
DECLARE @index INT
SET @index = 0

WHILE @index < 10
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.table_name(Index)
    VALUES( CAST(@index AS VARCHAR(50)) )  -- or whatever type you need....

    SET @index = @index + 1
END
```